# Getting an item's AssetID using the name or Instance ID?

Tags: node.js, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I'm using Node-Steam and I want to get an item's AssetID with the item's name or Instance ID. For example, I would want my bot to return a list of AssetID's of the keys in my inventory when I used the `"Mann Co. Supply Crate Key"`.

Comment: I'm curious too. Has anyone an idea how to get the AssetID by the item name?